# Uber developers API /request/[request_id] endpiont does not have waypoints for UberPOOL

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to read the waypoints for UberPOOL trips, but they are not being populated by the API.  This is the process that I am going through:

1. Call the /history endpoint to get a list of trips
2. Call the /request/[request_id] for each trip to get the details
3. Check the product id and make sure it is a "POOL" type product
4. Read the waypoints node

...but none of the trips have any waypoints.   What am I doing wrong?  Ideally, I would like the start/end location of each UberPOOL trip, and was hoping to the the waypoints as a workaround, because the start location in the history is just the city and not the actual pickup location.

Answer (score 1):

Waypoints are available only for trips with the status 'not-completed', we will update our documentation accordingly. Thanks for bringing this up.

The following fields are populated only when a trip is active:

- driver
- vehicle
- location
- eta
- surge_multiplier
- pickup
- destination
- riders
- waypoints

An example response for a completed trip request:

```
{
  "status": "completed",
  "product_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d",
  "request_id": "2b61e340-27bd-4937-8304-122009e4a393",
  "driver": null,
  "location": null,
  "vehicle": null,
  "shared": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Is there a way to get a relatively accurate start/end for a completed trip?